# Syntax error at <!doctype> on $("body").load() or $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load part of a HTML document into another document with jQuery, like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("body").load("index.html #tower");
};
```

But I am getting a syntax error at the first line of the document to be loaded (`<!doctype html>`). I also get this error everytime I try to use `$.get(document.php)` in any way.

I am unexperienced with jQuery but I haven't found any solutions to this yet.

The error I get on both Firefox and Chrome is very plain and lacks information at all. It just says `syntax error`.

index.html (heavily simplified):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>Media links and meta
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <ul class="menu"></ul>
        </div>
        <div id="left-column"></div>
        <ul id="tower">
            <li>
                <div class="place"></div>
            </li>
            ...More li
        </ul>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're calling getScript on an HTML file, inside an load, which makes no sense. You load() the HTML file with the fragment identifier in the string. See [the documentation for `load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake. The code should be fine now, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Include the text of the error in your question. Also provide us with a simplified version of index.html. There's no reason for you getting a syntax error when using load in the updated manner.

Comment: I think, first of all, you have to .load `html` document to some variable, then you have to use `DOM` to track and get element which `id` is `#tower`

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you have `getScript` in there...it returns a promise and is definitely not compatible with what you are trying to do

Try

```
$("body").load("index.html #tower");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("index.html").done(function (response) {
    $("body").html(response);
}
```

Comment: doing it this way you need to manually filter out `$('#tower')` from within the response and insert that